# Sound problem (chipset ALC280 and kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64)

Tags: debian, audio

I recently installed Debian Wheezy and sound doesn't work (glitches/distortions).

Output of `lspci -v | grep -A 6 Audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wellsburg HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0617
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69
    Memory at fb130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 094e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at fb080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

It seems Intel Corporation Wellsburg HD Audio Controller uses chipset ALC280 and I suppose it is not supported?

I really could not find a working solution for this problem.

Output of `uname -r`:

```
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: use `lspci -v | grep -A 6 Audio` it should say "Kernel driver in use" and that will show if there is a driver in use for the card or not.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I just updated the question.

Comment: Do you have the alsa-utils installed? if so, you need to run `alsamixer` in an open terminal and turn automute off as it is on by default. Also, sometimes it helps to also press F6 and then select your card from the list (also using alsamixer).

Comment: The card is not on mute, I have checked that. The problem is crackling/distorted sound.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently there is an incompatibility issue with ALC280 chipset and kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64.

My solution involved downloading the Realtek Linux driver (3.0) from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), unpacking it, and configuring it for Intel sound cards, using:

```
./configure --with-cards=hda-intel
```

then running

```
make
make install
```

Since I am using ALSA and PulseAudio, I ran

```
sudo purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

to reset some settings, then I checked whether there is an option line for snd-hda-intel in the alsa config file by running

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and commented out (or removed) the line

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 model=medion
```

then rebooted.

I also made sure to unmute ALSA, by running alsamixer and using "m" to unmute all channels.

And everything worked.

I would like to thank [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236) tutorial for providing some useful information as well.